# Sum and Average in a txt file array VBA

Tags: arrays, vb.net, visual-studio

I'm trying to display an average from a txt file that has both restaurant names and net worth in a list.  I'm displaying it in a label.  I'm still learning Visual Basic, so I'm not even sure if my code is just a bunch of garbage.  Here's what I've got.  Not only is it not displaying anything, but it also has an error

> "Structure "Integer" cannot be indexed because it has no default
>   value"

for `intNumber`.  Here's what I have:

```
Private Sub btnCompute_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles 
btnCompute.Click
    Dim objReader As IO.StreamReader
    Dim strLocationAndNameOfFile As String = "I:\franchise.txt"
    Dim IntTotal As Integer
    Dim intNumber As Integer
    Dim intElement As Integer
    Dim intAverage As Integer
    Dim intCount As Integer = 10
    If IO.File.Exists(strLocationAndNameOfFile) Then
        objReader = IO.File.OpenText(strLocationAndNameOfFile)
        For Each intElement In intNumber(strLocationAndNameOfFile)
            IntTotal += intElement
        Next

        intAverage = IntTotal / intCount
        lblAverageCost.Text = intAverage.ToString("C")
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Your question states VBA but no mention of VBA in question or even vba code?

Comment: `intNumber(strLocationAndNameOfFile)` doesn't make sense. You opened a StreamReader but didn't read anything from it.  Do a Google search for examples of reading lines via a StreamReader.

Comment: Also, unless you know there will always be 10 rows in the file, initialize intCount to 0 and then increment it inside your loop.

Answer (score 0):

Although you are opening the text file, you're not actually reading it. Also there are a few slightly different ways I'd do things - have a look at the code an comments.

```
    Dim strLocationAndNameOfFile As String = "I:\franchise.txt"
    Dim IntTotal As Integer
    Dim intAverage As Integer
    Dim intNumberCount As Integer
    'Use a string array to store the file contents

    'instead of using a separate intElements variable (which btw you defined as an individual
    'integer instead of an array, just use the string array to store the text of the file
    'without also having to use an integer array. In the loop below, each element of the string
    'array is parsed into an integer as needed, so no need for an extra array
    Dim fileLines() As String

    If IO.File.Exists(strLocationAndNameOfFile) Then
        'The  using statement opens the file and the end using statement will close the file and
        'dispose of the sr object. Its important to close a file when you're done using it
        Using sr As New StreamReader(strLocationAndNameOfFile)
            'This line does three things. .ReadToEnd reads all the lines in the file and then splits the
            'lines into individual strings. I'm assuming that the lines end with a VbCrLf and not a VbCr
            'Finally those individual lines are stored in the string array
            fileLines = sr.ReadToEnd.Split(vbCrLf)
            'file is closed here and the sr object is disposed
        End Using

        'Here the code loops through each element of fileLines and trys to parse them into an integer and
        'assin the integer to intNumber. If successful, the number is added to the total and 1 is added to
        'intNumberCount to keep track of the number of successfully parsed numbers
        For Each line As String In fileLines
            Dim intNumber As Integer
            If Integer.TryParse(line, intNumber) Then
                IntTotal += intNumber
                intNumberCount += 1
            End If
        Next
        'finally the average is calculated 
        intAverage = IntTotal / intNumberCount
        lblAverageCost.Text = intAverage.ToString("C")
    End If
```